Why is the electron gain enthalpy of Al negative?
Aluminum has ${1s^22s^22p^63s^23p^1}$ electronic configuration. I'm unable to see any benefit it could have from gaining an electron. Yet, Aluminum has a negative electron gain enthalpy/positive electron affinity. Could someone please explain why this is so?

You got it backwards - atoms are generally OK with getting another electron, unless they got something to lose.

There is a rule that only atoms with the spherical symmetry of electron density have negative electron affinity (some of them like $\ce{Sr, Ba}$ just very small positive one).
All others have positive electron affinity.
The reason for this can be explained even by classical electrostatics. Objects with zero net charge act toward other objects as a not charged object only if their internal charge distribution has spherical symmetry.
Atoms of aluminium with one electron in a p orbital do not have spherical symmetry of the charge distribution, therefore acts toward an external electron as if they have nonzero positive residual net charge.
By other words, the screening/shielding of the charge of a nucleus by charges of electrons is complete only if their distribution has the spherical symmetry.
